# Is this possible to generate subarray in O(n) time?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, time-complexity

I am trying to genarate subarray with the help of following code but the time complexity of this code in O(n^3). Please help me to find out the most optimal way.

My code is following:

```
 static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> solve(List<Integer> a) {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 

    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<a.size();j++)
        {
           ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();  
           for(int k=i+1;k<=j;k++)
               {
                    temp.add(a.get(k));

               }

           res.add(temp)

        }

    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: *I am trying to generate subarray* on what basis ?

Comment: There is no better way to do this other than `O(n^3)` if you have to generate all possible subarrays. But I think your goal to solve another problem, right?

Comment: Yes my goal is to find all the subarray whose sum is less than 5.

Comment: But I want to see the optomal way for array. If this is not possible in O(n) to generate subarray then I got my answer.

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to "Is this possible in O(n)?" or so? Also some example input & output might clarify this question a bit (referring to "find all the subarray whose sum is less than 5").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the lists to be independent of the original list `a`, you may use `List`'s `subList` method.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

This will reduce the complexity to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Is there any way for o(n)?

Comment: No, even assuming all entries in the list are non-negative, this is not possible. For each `n` you can construct an input list `a` which yields `O(n²)` many subsets with sum less than 5: For odd `n`, `n = 2*m + 1` let `a[m] = 4` and `a[m] = 0` otherwise. Then all combinations `(i, j)` with `i ≤ m` and `m ≤ j` yields valid sublists (with start index `i` and end index `j`). Clearly this gives you approx. `m² ~ (n/2)²` solutions.

Comment: If all entries are larger than 0 (at least 1), then each resulting sub-array has at most 4 entries. The possible results (omitting the empty result) are at most `(1+2+3+4)*n` many. Just iterate the start index `i` and in an inner loop the end index `j` from `i+1` to `i+4` and create a `subList(i, j+1)`.  This is clearly `O(4*n) = O(n)`.

Comment: Of couse in the last algorithm I mentioned, just create the sublist if the sum is less than 5. This may be optimized by skipping larger arrays if you already know that a subarray has a too high sum.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks.